# Laravel scheduler is scheduled dailyAt('07:00') but running at (00:00) means at midnight

Tags: laravel, scheduler

I have added a scheduler at dailyAt('07:00) but it is running at midnight(00:00) in laravel. I have also added the timezone parameter. Please help

Comment: Is your server time correct?

Comment: Yes. Other notifications are working correct except this dailyAt

Comment: Can you share an example of how defined your scheduled tasks along with the output of `date -u` (if on a Linux system or a system with a Linux type shell)